# How to fix ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on Chrome? (PHP cURL)

Tags: php, curl

I have problem only on Chrome. On Firefox working very well.

```
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');            
$curl = curl_init(); // CURL BAŞLATTIK
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
$veri = curl_exec($curl);
```

... continue ...

```
foreach($data as $dataa){
    echo $dataa;
}
```

This problem have only on Chrome: `"ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"`.
This codes working on Firefox very well.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you share your $link

Comment: $link = "https://www.google.com/search?q=search+data"

Comment: getting 301 Moved printing $veri variable

Comment: Could you post the full code

Comment: When I printing with this code: print_r($veri) . its working. I need without print_r

Comment: We have no idea what $data is supposed to be, so we can not possibly tell you what is going on. But you are not supposed to scrape search results from Google in such a fashion to begin with, so the problem will likely go away on its own once they block your server IP …

Comment: I would like to remind you that something called "proxy" was invented. When $veri (Google Page) coming. System is working. So not working only Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed. I am using VPN on my browser. The connection over time of VPN is 30 seconds. Thats why when I using this page, after 30 seconds page said me: "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

First Way: Close VPN on your browser and computer.
Second Way: Increase execution time on your server with php.ini.